# RxJava (Android) PublishProcessor not working

Tags: android, system.reactive, reactive

I would like to use PublishProcessor that would work like that:

- is fed with some init data (randomly when user scrolls view - Integer in the example),
- it does some background job (downloads data based on the init data)
- when finish downloading notifies about newly downloaded data type (String in the example)

It should be all the time ready to receive and handle new init data.

I've prepared simple code to test it but it doesn't work.

```
PublishProcessor processor = PublishProcessor.create();
    processor.map(new Function<Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Integer o) throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            DevLog.d("test","executing "+o);
            return String.valueOf(o)+"aaa";
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
        Subscription sub;
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(org.reactivestreams.Subscription s) {
            DevLog.d("test","onsubscribe "+s);
            sub = s;
            sub.request(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            DevLog.d("test","next "+s);
            sub.request(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            DevLog.d("test","error "+t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            DevLog.d("test","complete");
        }
    });
    processor.onNext(666);
    processor.onNext(123);
    processor.onNext(456);
    DevLog.d("test","nextsent");
```

All I get in the logcat is:

- onsubscribe 0
- nextsent

I would rather expect:

- nextsent
- executing 666
- executing 123
- executing 456
- next 666aaa
- next 123aaa
- next 456aaa

Comment: Is the `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` the one that is running `DevLog.d("test","nextsent");`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, this whole code is in Activity#onCreate()

Comment: Then your code is blocking. Try running a background thread scheduler and see you get the results you expect.